# SuiteCRM Best Practice to create new fields

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have created a custom module using Module Builder in the SuiteCRM, i have deployed it before one month. Now again, i want to add more fields to those modules, i found two ways ( Studio, Module Builder) to create fields for a module, Could anyone tell me which options( Studio or Module Builder ) is better and best practice to create new fields for this existing module in SuiteCRM.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your circumstances.

If your module *has not been used in a production capacity*, it would be arguably better to re-deploy the module again, removing and recreating the tables.

Fields in modules created via module builder are created in the core table, as opposed to a *_cstm* table. This may not mean much in smaller systems, but in larger systems, multi-table queries might slow things down.

If your module **is** currently used in a production capacity, re-deploying a module via module builder will cause some pretty catastrophic changes to any changes made via studio. It may also remove the tables, losing any data entered. Studio is made for ongoing configuration of the application, and is [thoroughly documented](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Versions/6.5/Ent/Administration_Guide/Developer_Tools/Studio/) by SugarCRM.

**In summary**, if your module is already in use: Use Studio. If it's not used yet, you might want to redeploy the module for efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

There are different approches to counter.
Lets first understand, how fields are created in database from all these techniques.
1- module builder : all fields are created in main table of module.
After this if you need to add more fields, coz sugar doesnot recommend to reinstall same module.
So creating fields from studio will create in cstm table, which will then difficult to handle any more customization.
So the workaround is to add fields in modules vardefs, so fields created to main table